# Get every places names in geonames with SPARQL DBPEDIA

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, geonames

I'm quite new to sparql.

I founded this query to get  all country in the UN

```
select distinct ?s
where { ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/WikicatMemberStatesOfTheUnitedNations> }
```

So I tried to adapt it to Geonames with:

```
select distinct ?s
where { ?s a <http://dbpedia.org/page/GeoNames> }
```

But it doesn't work. How can I get every place's name in geonames?

I hope someone can help me with that!

Comment: what do you expect `?s a <http://dbpedia.org/page/GeoNames>` would match or means? It basically means "instance of" relation, so you're asking for everything that is instance of GeoNames - sound wierd, right? The idea is to find the concept names in the GeoNames dtaaset first, then use those in your query. And `http://dbpedia.org/page/GeoNames` is partially from DBpedia namespace, but even then `/page/` just denotes the HTML representation of the original entity, which in your case would be `http://dbpedia.org/resource/GeoNames` (which indeed doesn't exists because two different datasets)

Answer (score 0):

Every publisher uses its own namespace and method to generate URIs of the published entities. The nice thing about Linked Open Data is that it allows such independence while URIs can still be linked using agreed open standards. When different URI represent the same thing, this is declared by linking them with `owl:sameAs`.

Your query attempt assumes that DPpedia and Geonames use the same URIs, if I understood correctly the intention (I'm not sure qhat you mean by "to adapt"). What you need to do is use two separate variables, and then specify that from the `owl:sameAs` mappings, you want only those from Geonames.

```
select distinct *

where { ?cuntryDBpedia a <http://dbpedia.org/class/yago/WikicatMemberStatesOfTheUnitedNations> ;

        owl:sameAs ?countryGeonames .

FILTER REGEX (?countryGeonames,"geonames.org")

 }
```

Comment: I would like all place's name in geonames dataset.
like country, town, villages, building, montains name and stuff like that basiclly.
sorry I wasn't clear engouh in my first question

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to get. You may consider editing your question with reference to the properties and classes of the [GeoNames ontology](http://www.geonames.org/ontology/documentation.html)